# relation tableName does not exist - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a database named **mimic** on my **postgres DB** .
I'm trying to execute this command :

```
select hadm_id from admission_ids where hadm_id in (select distinct on (subject_id) hadm_id from (select * from admissions order by admittime) tt
```

but I receive this error :
 **relation "admissions" does not exist**
When I modify the query by changing admissions to mimic iii.admissions it works.
knowing that mimic iii is the schema , when I type this query this is the result that appears:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mimiciii';
     table_name     
--------------------
 admissions
 callout
 caregivers
 datetimeevents
 ...
```

My question is what can I do to make the user type only the name of the table without using the schema.tableName ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is what can I do to make the user type only the name of
>   the table without using the schema.tableName ?

By putting the schema into your [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

Besides `SET search_path TO ...` which is valid for the duration of the session, it can be made permanent per user with `ALTER USER username SET search_path='...'`, or per database with  `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET search_path='...'`.